# History of calculus-based optimization

Tags: calculus, optimization, math-history, conic-sections

I would like to know:
- who started with calculus-based optimization problems and when it was,
- if there is a book focusing on history of ellipses/ conic sections 
- if someone ever tried to calculate minimum distance between 2 ellipses in 2D back then

Anything related to the abovementioned is welcomed too.

Comment: Probably [Fermat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_(stationary_points))

Comment: Newton solved the brachistochrone problem.  So it seems like the inventor of calculus (along with Leibniz) was himself doing some calculus-based optimization.